# Impala LDAPS Always Fails With Unknown CA

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala

I am trying to use ldaps to verify connections to an Impala database with the following configuration in the Impala Command Line Argument Advanced Configuration Snippet configuration item in Cloudera Manager:

--enable_ldap=true 
--ldap_uri=ldaps://testServ.domain.com
--ldap_ca_certificate="/home/impala/testServ.domain.pem"

Where testServ.domain.pem is the ldap server certificate.

Using wireshark I can see that after receiving the certificate during SSL negotiation Impala always responds with an Unknown CA alert.
I can successfully connect with Impala using unencrypted ldap and I can connect with a different ldaps enabled program using the provided certificate, so I doubt the issue is on the ldap server.

Is there another configuration parameter I need or a way to determine why Impala always rejects the ldap servers certificate?